# How to make a ~90 mm diameter 50 cm forearm roller as cheaply as possible?

Tags: pipe

I want to make a 90±5mm diameter forearm roller.

It is a cylinder about 50 cm long. If it is a heavy material on its own, ideal. If it is not a heavy material, it must be possible to attach a string to its middle so that weights can be hung on the string and the string can be rolled up by turning the rod.

I want to make this for as cheap as possible. I already explored using plastic duct piping (downpipe) for a smaller size, 68mm, and it was pretty cheap, £4.70 for 2.5m of it which I sawed down to size and drilled a hole through. I bet cheaper options might have existed.

I can't find cheap 90mm straight pipes online, so looking for help or other options.

Comment: Wouldn't [[home-gym]] be a great tag?

Comment: You'd have been much better off editing your previous question instead of asking a whole new one that includes the details the other should have had.

Comment: @FreeMan idk, I think they're different questions. the other question is "how to find pipes of specific diameters", and this question is "how to make a forearm roller"

Comment: In that case, _both_ would be off-topic. One as shopping advice and the other would probably fall into the Crafts category. Don't worry, it takes more than one person to close a question, so if I'm a significant minority, this will remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Since I live in a region where millimeter measurements aren't common (yes, that region) the first thing I did was convert to inches to get an estimate of size so that I could look for something. I noticed 90mm is very very close to (approximately 1mm larger than) 3.5 inches.
3.5 inches happens to be the outside diameter of pipes (plastic/pvc and steel) that are nominally 3 inches (inside is approximately 3 inches).

Since you're looking on the Internet for pipes, you may be able to buy US stock (either from a US outlet, or from a manufacturer that makes goods overseas for sale in the US). I don't know that 88.9mm would be a common size outside the US market though, so if you're not able to purchase these online you'd have to find something completely different.

Comment: 90mm can be sourced pretty much anywhere in the UK… & presumably in the EU too. It's one of the stock sizes.

Comment: @Tetsujin what places have it in stock?

Comment: Also your answer reminds me of the distinction between inside and outside diameter. I am aiming for 90mm outside diameter

Comment: I can only repeat my comment from your last question…"Where do you live that google won't find pages of results for "90mm pipe", or 70mm, for that matter?"

Comment: @Tetsujin in the UK

Comment: Then type `90mm pipe` into google, pick a merchant. …or if you only want a bit, go to a merchant or a building site & ask if they've got a spare bit. 50cm of pipe is just an offcut to most people; they'd likely give it to you for free.

Comment: @Tetsujin I literally can't find anything cheaper than £20.57. I will try contacting directly as you suggest